# Relative size and location of visuals

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to build my report on Power BI, on my tab there are 3 matrix. When I filter by one of the fields, all my matrix reduce their size and there are some big white holes.

Is there a feature or tool that allows me to place one matrix under another each time they are resized, to avoid those huge white holes?

I searched for the PowerBI documentation but did not find anything to solve my problem.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. However there might be more optimal solution than having 3 matrices, so feel free to provide sample report screenshot, so somebody can suggest a workaround.

Comment: I can't provide a screenshot because is confidential data, I just wanted to know if that was possible, if is not, bad luck.